# Use of Section header and searchable causes bug?

Tags: swiftui

I have in my code a Form which contains multiple conditional sections.

I want the form to be searchable ONLY if one section is included.

```swift
if myCondition {
   Section {
      Text("My Section Contents")
   } header: {
      Text("My Section Header")
   }.searchable(text: $filterText, placement: .navigationBarBrawer(displaymode: .always))
}
```

This however seems to break the header which renders normally without the searchable.

Any ideas? Is there another way to conditionally include the search bar?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            if canSearch {
                Section {
                    Text("Now you can search")
                        .searchable(text: $filterText, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always))
                } header: {
                    Text("Search")
                }
            }
```